# JQuery Prepend on SVG

Tags: jquery, svg

Why does this work

```
$(parent)[0].appendChild(el);
```

and this dont?

```
$(parent)[0].prepend(el);
```

Coming from:

```
makeSVG('.svg-global', 'g', {id:'setores'}, true);

makeSVG('#setores',x.name, x.data,false);
```

And the function itself:

```
function makeSVG(parent, tag, attrs,pre) {
            var el= document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', tag);
            for (var k in attrs)
                el.setAttribute(k, attrs[k]);
            if(pre){
                $(parent)[0].prepend(el);
            }else{
                $(parent)[0].appendChild(el);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript has no prepend method, jQuery does

```
$(parent).eq(0).prepend(el);
```

and

```
$(parent).eq(0).append(el);
```

are jQuery methods, while `appendChild` is a native javascript method.

When you use `[0]` you get the first underlying native javascript element in the collection, and jQuery methods does not work on regular DOM nodes.

Unfortunately there is no `prependChild` method for native nodes, you'd have to use insertBefore

```
parent.insertBefore(el, parent.firstChild);
```